# 2nd animation starts at top of screen instead of location of previous animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two animations that are to occur one after the other. The first one works as expected, however, the 2nd animation jumps to the very top of the screen at the first animation's `onAnimationEnd()` call. A balloon ImageView "floats" up to the center of the screen, and it is supposed to expand (the rest will be implemented later. I'm just trying to get this part to work). The first animation is pure Java, not xml.

The second animation's xml (bounce.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

My BounceInterpolator class:

```
public class BounceInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    private double mAmplitude = 1;
    private double mFrequency = 10;

    BounceInterpolator(double amplitude, double frequency) {
        mAmplitude = amplitude;
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }
    public float getInterpolation(float time) {
        return (float) (-1 * Math.pow(Math.E, -time/ mAmplitude) * Math.cos(mFrequency * time) + 1);
    }
}
```

And finally the class where it all happens:

```
public class CelebrateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView purple_balloon_1;
    Animation anim;
    Animation bounceAnim;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    static int height;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_celebrate);

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.first_love);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        layout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        purple_balloon_1 = findViewById(R.id.purple_balloon_1);
        slideUp();
    }

    public void slideUp() {
        Animation slide = null;
        slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, height, height / 2 - 100);
        slide.setDuration(15000);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        purple_balloon_1.startAnimation(slide);

        bounceAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CelebrateActivity.this, R.anim.bounce);
        BounceInterpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
        bounceAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                purple_balloon_1.startAnimation(bounceAnim); //Where the 2nd animation is supposed to start. It works, but it jumps to the top of the screen.
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why does it jump to the top of the screen, and how can I set the Y coordinate to the location of the ImageView to prevent said jumping?

Comment: dont use view animations -
 instead use property animators, for more refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)

Comment: view animations are for cavemen - they were used in android's ancient times ;-)

Comment: I'll get with the times and go back to the drawing board. Thanks for the tip. :-)

Comment: [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#property-vs-view) you can start with, good luck....

Comment: seems that you can declare your "main" animator like [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property) and add your interpolator to the second child animator at runtime

Answer (score 0):

@pskink - Thank you for the tips. I went with ObjectAnimator and AnimatorSet. I got rid of both of my xml files and the BounceInterpolator class, which saved a lot of code in the process. The animation is working perfectly now.

Again, thank you.

```
public class CelebrateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView purple_balloon_1;
    //Animation slide;
    //Animation grow;
    AnimatorSet animatorSet;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    static int height;

    public static final String TAG = "CelebrateActivity.this";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_celebrate);

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.first_love);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        layout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        purple_balloon_1 = findViewById(R.id.purple_balloon_1);

        animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator slide = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(purple_balloon_1, "translationY", height, height / 2);
        slide.setDuration(15000);
        ObjectAnimator growX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(purple_balloon_1, "scaleX", 1.5f);
        growX.setDuration(500);
        ObjectAnimator growY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(purple_balloon_1, "scaleY", 1.5f);
        growY.setDuration(500);

        animatorSet.playTogether(growX, growY);
        animatorSet.playSequentially(slide, growX);
        animatorSet.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: imho with xml you would save a bit of java code (just `AnimatorInflater`), and where is your bounce effect here?

Comment: I used the wrong terminology. It wasn't a "bounce" effect. It was actually a grow effect. I will look into the XML version as well and implement it later. Thanks again.

Comment: take a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property, the example at the bottom of `Property animation` section is almost the same like your case

Comment: and the last thing about property animators: for simple cases you can use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#view-prop-animator)